# Remove source along with cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

I have a custom cordova plugin that includes both a *.aar file and *.kt (kotlin) files. When I remove and re-add my plugin (it's in the local file system, it fails because the remove step didn't actually remove all of it; here's an example error:

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'com.rsginc.mobilesurvey': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"/Users/me/code/ms-client-echidna/platforms/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/rsginc/mobilesurvey/BreadCrumbs.kt" already exists!
    at copyNewFile (/Users/me/code/ms-client-echidna/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:261:45)
    ...
```

I have a workaround - an alias that will remove the plugin, rm the source, and then reinstall it, but that's ugly to share with other developers in my group.

Here's a line from my plugin.xml (that matches the above error):

```
<source-file src="src/android/BreadCrumbs.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/kotlin/com/rsginc/mobilesurvey" />
```

Is there something else I can add to my plugin.xml so it will clean up during the 'cordova plugin rm ...'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (as of `cordova-android@7.1.1`), Cordova [only removes `.java` files](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/bin/templates/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js#L39-L41) when plugins are uninstalled from the Android platform.

You can use `--force` when re-adding the plugin to ignore the error that occurs because the `.kt` source files already exist in the android platform project.

Or, if you take a look at my [cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin) example plugin, you can add the [uninstall hook script](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin/blob/master/hooks/on-uninstall.js) to your plugin which removes any `.kt` specified in the `plugin.xml` from the android platform project.